# Convert R dataframe into tough JSON list of lists for d3.hierarchy model

Tags: r, json, d3.js

**Edit: I have cleaned up a bit the question posting, and added a bounty. I will be afk for a few days, but getting this resolved would be a huge help**

I would like to create using d3 a d3.hierarchy of a tree model, using basketball data. I essentially want to create a bracket structured as such:

[image]

...where the graph / model is a tree where each node has exactly two children (except for all of the end / leaf nodes, of course). This is a textbook example of when you'd want to use the d3.tree() and d3.hierarchy() functionalities, but it requires a JSON in a fairly specific format for the d3.hierarchy command. In particular, for a bracket of 8 basketball teams in a tournament that goes 8 - 4 - 2 - 1, the JSON data needs to be formatted like this:

```
const playoffData = {
  "name": "Rockets",
  "round": 4,
  "id": 15,
  "children": [
    { 
      "name": "Rockets",
      "round": 3,
      "id": 14,
      "children": [
        { 
          "name": "Rockets",
          "round": 2,
          "id": 9,
          "children": [
            { 
              "name": "Rockets", 
              "round": 1, 
              "id": 1 
            },
            { 
              "name": "Timberwolves", 
              "round": 1,
              "id": 8 
            }
          ]
        },
        { 
          "name": "Jazz",
          "round": 2,
          "id": 12,
          "children": [
            { 
              "name": "Jazz", 
              "round": 1, 
              "id": 4 
            },
            { 
              "name": "Thunder",
              "round": 1, 
              "id": 5
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      "name": "Warriors",
      "round": 3, 
      "id": 13,
      "children": [
        { 
          "name": "Warriors",
          "round": 2, 
          "id": 10,
          "children": [
            { 
              "name": "Warriors", 
              "round": 1, 
              "id": 2 
            },
            {
              "name": "Spurs", 
              "round": 1, 
              "id": 7
            }
          ]
        },
        { 
          "name": "Pelicans",
          "round": 2, 
          "id": 11,
          "children": [
            { 
              "name": "Pelicans",
              "round": 1,
              "id": 3
            },
            { 
              "name": "Trail Blazers",
              "round": 1, 
              "id": 6
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Note the nested nature of the JSONs. The **root** node corresponds with the winner of the bracket, and **leaf** nodes correspond to teams in the first round of the bracket.

I have the following R dataframe of basketball data for the bracket:

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15), teamname = c("Rockets", "Warriors", "Trail Blazers", 
"Jazz", "Thunder", "Pelicans", "Spurs", "Timberwolves", "Rockets", 
"Warriors", "Pelicans", "Jazz", "Rockets", "Warriors", "Rockets"
), conference = c("West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West"), seeding = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), round = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 4), child1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
9, 11, 13), child2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 7, 
6, 5, 12, 10, 14), wins = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), losses = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), completed = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), winprobs = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("id", "teamname", "conference", "seeding", 
"round", "child1", "child2", "wins", "losses", "completed", "winprobs"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 25L, 26L, 29L), class = "data.frame")


> mydata
> playoff.data


   id      teamname conference seeding round child1 child2 wins losses completed winprobs
1   1       Rockets       West       1     1     NA     NA    0      0     FALSE       NA
2   2      Warriors       West       2     1     NA     NA    0      0     FALSE       NA
3   3 Trail Blazers       West       3     1     NA     NA    0      0     FALSE       NA
4   4          Jazz       West       4     1     NA     NA    0      0     FALSE       NA
5   5       Thunder       West       5     1     NA     NA    0      0     FALSE       NA
6   6      Pelicans       West       6     1     NA     NA    0      0     FALSE       NA
7   7         Spurs       West       7     1     NA     NA    0      0     FALSE       NA
8   8  Timberwolves       West       8     1     NA     NA    0      0     FALSE       NA
17  9       Rockets       West      NA     2      1      8    0      0     FALSE       NA
18 10      Warriors       West      NA     2      2      7    0      0     FALSE       NA
19 11      Pelicans       West      NA     2      3      6    0      0     FALSE       NA
20 12          Jazz       West      NA     2      4      5    0      0     FALSE       NA
25 13       Rockets       West      NA     3      9     12    0      0     FALSE       NA
26 14      Warriors       West      NA     3     11     10    0      0     FALSE       NA
29 15       Rockets       West      NA     4     13     14    0      0     FALSE       NA
```

If you can tell, **My R Dataframe** has a row for what will be each node in my d3 graph. Notice the tree structure in particular, and the child1 and child2 helper columns for identifying children - for the Final Round (row 15), its child nodes are the two nodes in the previous round (13 and 14). For row 13 (the semi finals), its children nodes are 9 and 12, etc. The first 8 rows are the first round, and therefore these are leaf nodes and have no children.

Its a bit long, but I wanted to include the whole JSON and R dataframe to keep things clear. I would also like other dataframe columns (wins, losses, win probs) included in the JSON structure, however for a bit of brevity, I did not show these in the JSON above.

**A last note:** while I work mainly in R, this is a d3 graph I am making, and as such there is quite a bit of javascript coding that I must do for this. My opinion is that R is better for this type of data manip, however since this is a nested JSON object we're dealing with, maybe JS is better. If there's an eas(ier) solution that involves using javasript to map a 2D JSON version of the R dataframe into the desired nested JSON, that would probably be sufficient as well.

Any help with this is appreciated! I promise to select a top answer once I return to award the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this recursive function together with `jsonlite::toJSON()`:

```
get_node <- function(df, id) {
  node <- as.list(df[df$id == id, c("teamname", "round", "id")])
  names(node) = c("name", "round", "id")
  id1 <- df[df$id == id,]$child1
  id2 <- df[df$id == id,]$child2
  if (!is.na(id1) && !is.na(id2)) {
    child1 <- get_node(df, id1)
    child2 <- get_node(df, id2)
    if (child1$name == node$name)
      node$children <- list(child1, child2)
    else if (child2$name == node$name)
      node$children <- list(child2, child1)
    else
      stop("Inout data is inconsistent!")
  }
  node
}

jsonlite::toJSON(get_node(playoffs, 15), pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

With your data I get the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Rockets",
  "round": 4,
  "id": 15,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Rockets",
      "round": 3,
      "id": 13,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Rockets",
          "round": 2,
          "id": 9,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Rockets",
              "round": 1,
              "id": 1
            },
            {
              "name": "Timberwolves",
              "round": 1,
              "id": 8
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jazz",
          "round": 2,
          "id": 12,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Jazz",
              "round": 1,
              "id": 4
            },
            {
              "name": "Thunder",
              "round": 1,
              "id": 5
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Warriors",
      "round": 3,
      "id": 14,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Warriors",
          "round": 2,
          "id": 10,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Warriors",
              "round": 1,
              "id": 2
            },
            {
              "name": "Spurs",
              "round": 1,
              "id": 7
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Pelicans",
          "round": 2,
          "id": 11,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Pelicans",
              "round": 1,
              "id": 6
            },
            {
              "name": "Trail Blazers",
              "round": 1,
              "id": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: With my full dataset, sometimes the child name is NA (if a particular playoff series has not started yet, the teamname column would be blank). I didn't make this clear, but the update is fairly simple I think (simply removing that last else case does the trick)

Comment: although I'm a tidyverse fan, for readability and because I was looking for a recursive solution, I will accept this answer, although both are great. Thanks guys

Comment: @Canovice You could also use the previous version that did not adjust the order of the child elements. It is even shorter ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

We reformat your data and split the data.frame in 4 data.frames.

Then we join those, nesting the relevant columns at each step.

Finally we use `toJSON` to finish the job :

```
my.split <- my.data %>%
  gather(temp,children,child1,child2) %>%
  select(-temp) %>%
  select(name= teamname,round,id,children) %>% # change here to keep more columns
  distinct %>%
  split(.$round)

my.split[[1]] %>%
  select(-children) %>%
  right_join(my.split[[2]],by=c(id="children"),suffix=c("",".y")) %>%
  nest(1:3) %>% # change here to keep more columns
  setNames(names(my.split[[1]])) %>%
  right_join(my.split[[3]],by=c(id="children"),suffix=c("",".y")) %>%
  nest(1:4) %>% # change here to keep more columns
  setNames(names(my.split[[1]])) %>%
  right_join(my.split[[4]],by=c(id="children"),suffix=c("",".y")) %>%
  nest(1:4) %>% # change here to keep more columns
  setNames(names(my.split[[1]])) %>%
  jsonlite::toJSON(pretty=TRUE)
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Rockets",
    "round": 4,
    "id": 15,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Rockets",
        "round": 3,
        "id": 13,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Rockets",
            "round": 2,
            "id": 9,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Rockets",
                "round": 1,
                "id": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "Timberwolves",
                "round": 1,
                "id": 8
              }
              ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Jazz",
            "round": 2,
            "id": 12,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Jazz",
                "round": 1,
                "id": 4
              },
              {
                "name": "Thunder",
                "round": 1,
                "id": 5
              }
              ]
          }
          ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Warriors",
        "round": 3,
        "id": 14,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Pelicans",
            "round": 2,
            "id": 11,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Trail Blazers",
                "round": 1,
                "id": 3
              },
              {
                "name": "Pelicans",
                "round": 1,
                "id": 6
              }
              ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Warriors",
            "round": 2,
            "id": 10,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Warriors",
                "round": 1,
                "id": 2
              },
              {
                "name": "Spurs",
                "round": 1,
                "id": 7
              }
              ]
          }
          ]
      }
      ]
  }
  ]
```

Comment: The expected output has the winner always as the first child, even though that does not correspond to `child1` in the table. I am not sure if this is important for the OP.

Comment: indeed, I assumed OP built the output by hand and that it was either a mistake or irrelevant, but it's fair to point it out.

Comment: Actually id 13 is Rockets and id 14 is Warriors in OP's sample data, so I can only assume it's an error from OP, and your output seems to be the same as mine as far as I can tell. OP will probably let us know when he comes around.

Comment: @RalfStubner I don't have a preference when it comes to the ordering of the children, so long as the children are correct. Potentially when I create the graph using the data, the order will matter, but that's not something I've run into yet

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper

Comment: You can do any reordering you like after the first step `my.data %>%
  gather(temp,children,child1,child2)` by inserting something like `%>% arrange(teamname)`. The `right_join`s and `nest` should preserve that order so down the line you'll have the desired layout.